# multiple href parameters in facebook notification

Tags: facebook, notifications

i am trying to send an app-to-user Facebook notification with multiple href params.
the way im doing it now the link would look something like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/user-id/notifications?access_token=access|token&template=test_msg&href=?campaign=1

this sends the notification to the user just fine and when clicking the notification it takes the user to this link:

https://apps.facebook.com/mygame/?campaign=1&fb_source=notification&ref=notif&notif_t=app_notification

which also works as expected, the problem is that i want to add more parameters to this link, as in: campaign=1&tracking=2&someshit=3

i couldn't figure this out from the docs, i dunno if there is a limitation on href to only 1 param, it doesn't say so in the docs, but there is no example on how to send more than 1 param. i already tried to add more hrefs in the url but it doesn't work and only takes the last one.

iv'e seen other Facebook apps that do that like Slotomania, so i know there's a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so obviously it was much simpler than thought. it's possible to chain multiple parameters using %26 instead of & like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/user-id/notifications?access_token=access|token&template=test_msg&href=?campaign=1%26foo=bar%26someshit=3

hope this will help someone.